# Creating a boolean value for an if-else statement

Tags: c#

```
bool InUse = true;
while (InUse)
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the 2017 Wimbledon tournament! \n");
Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for a Default tournament");
Console.WriteLine("Press 2 for Women's single:");
Console.WriteLine("Press 3 for Men's single:");
Console.WriteLine("Press 4 for Women's double:");
Console.WriteLine("Press 5 for Men's double:");
Console.WriteLine("Press 6 for Mix double:");
Console.Write("Make a choice:");
int userValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if (userValue == 1 || userValue == 2 || userValue == 3 || userValue == 4 || userValue == 5 || userValue == 6)  
{
```

I can't seem to write a statement that returns a false and true value if anything is pressed correct or wrong. How would you guys do this? I was going to use a return true; but I cant seem to implement this.

Comment: This code will loop forever writing the same statement again and again. Did you miss a couple of braces?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already and take a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Also `while` without braces executing the first statement below it, hence `Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the 2017 Wimbledon tournament! \n");` will print indefinitely.

Comment: Also, have you even tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code will loop infinitely because you are missing a pair of braces. Try the following:

```
bool InUse = true;
while (InUse)
{
    // Content of the loop goes here
}
```

Note that your current code is equivalent to the following

```
bool InUse = true;
while (InUse)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the 2017 Wimbledon tournament! \n");
}
Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for a Default tournament");
// The rest of your program
```

Answer (score 1):

Your malformed `while` has already been addressed in @aochagavia's answer so I will concentrate on your input code. I would change

```
int userValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

to

```
char userValue = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

This has two advantages:

1. The user doesn't need to hit `Enter` after he typed the number
2. You don't have to explicitely deal with non numeric inputs

The evaluatuion of the input can then be like this:

```
inUse = false;    // assume valid input and set inUse to false to exit while
switch(userValue)
{
    case '1':
        // Handle Default tournament
        break;
    case '2':
        // Handle Women's single
        break;
    ... // Handle other valid numbers
    default:
        // Set inUse to true again to ask again
        inUse = true;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
int userValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

you can use:

```
int userValue;
bool wasOK = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userValue);
if (!wasOK)
{
  continue; // restart enclosing 'while' loop
}
```

After that, you could:

```
switch (userValue)
{
  // ...
}
```